# Post thumbnail linking on wordpress category

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, thumbnails

i use this code to show thumbnails'posts on my categories :

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
```

But I would like to turn them into link.
I try this code :

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But the text no longer appears to the right of the image, and the image is too large.

How to fix it plz ?
( source : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php $imageClass = array ( 'class' => "alignleft",); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', $imageClass); ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```